# Android Studio: Open every URL in WebView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

I want to turn a website into an app using the WebView. However, if I tap a link in the WebView, the app does not try to load the URL in the WebView, but in the browser (Chrome). How can I change this?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://100315.fuxnoten.online/webinfo/account/");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`setWebViewClient()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#setWebViewClient(android.webkit.WebViewClient))

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
...
```